# Remove duplicates and merge JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object. I need to remove the duplicates and merge the inner object using plain Javascript. How do I go about doing this?

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "abc",
    "nodes" :[
        {
            "nodeId" : 20,
            "nodeName" : "test1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "abc",
    "nodes" :[
        {
            "nodeId" : 21,
            "nodeName" : "test2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Following is the object that I expect as output.

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "abc",
    "nodes" :[
        {
            "nodeId" : 20,
            "nodeName" : "test1"
        },
        {
            "nodeId" : 21,
            "nodeName" : "test2"
        },
    ]
}]
```

Regards.

Shreerang

Comment: Maybe you could use a loop on your array, store already done items in another by ID after checked if the item is not already in.
Then do a merge function or google it.

Comment: So what would you do with an entry like {id:1, name: "def"... Is that a match or not?

Comment: You ask for too many.Give as your code try plz

Comment: @AdrianMay that case would not arise...

Comment: @Csdtesting I am putting together a fiddle. Posting it soon.

Comment: underscore.js and  deep_extend_javascript_objects_underscore_mixin.js i would use.i'll try it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First turn the JSON into a Javascript array so that you can easily access it:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then make an array for the result and loop through the items and compare against the items that you put in the result:

```
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var found = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
    if (result[j].id == arr[i].id && result[j].name == arr[i].name) {
      found = true;
      result[j].nodes = result[j].nodes.concat(arr[i].nodes);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Then you can create JSON from the array if that is the end result that you need:

```
json = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: That entire loop could be simplified using `Array.prototype.filter`. Especially since your example already uses `concat`.

Comment: @Sukima: Yes, it could, but `filter` isn't supported in as many browsers as `concat`. For example IE 5.5 supports `concat` but you need IE 9 or later to get support for `filter`.

Comment: Your still supporting IE 5?!?!!!! Oh God's you have my condolences. Also I noticed that trend to continue educating on the "old" way of things instead of embracing the more recent. Also there are poly-fills and they are worth learning. Lead by example.

Comment: @Sukima: Don't be silly. No, I'm not supporting IE 5, but IE 8 unless there is a good reason not to. In this case there isn't a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is called input, then this:

```
var inter = {};
for (var i in input) {
    if (!inter.hasOwnProperty(input[i].name)) {
        inter[input[i].name] = input[i].nodes;
        inter[input[i].name].name = input[i].name;
        inter[input[i].name].id = input[i].id;
    }
    else
        inter[input[i].name] = inter[input[i].name].concat(input[i].nodes)
}
```

results in:
    {"abc":[{"nodeId":20,"nodeName":"test1"},{"nodeId":21,"nodeName":"test2"}]}

You can see how I'm using an intermediate object keyed by whatever the match criterion is. It's an object rather than an array as you asked, but you can iterate it anyway. In fact you're probably better off with this structure than the array you asked for.

BTW, I shoved a couple of text-named properties: "id" and "name" into an array there. They don't show up in JSON.stringify but they're there.